# I need to set up eclipse with flex plugin

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

I want to work with flex from eclipse, could you tell me how to install the flex plugin within eclipse:

What version of eclipse do I need?

Where can I download the flex plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried Flex with Eclipse, I know for sure you can work with NetBeans IDE using FlexBean plugin. You can find the Eclipse/Flex plugin details below.

http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2005/08/setting-up-eclipse-for-flex.cfm

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are a lot of supossedly needed files that are have broken links, isn't there another solid source for those files?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder and download the Eclipse Plug-in of Flash Builder 4.

The installer will allow you to install the plugin into an existing Eclipse installation. One of the installation steps lets you select the Eclipse installation folder.

The system requirements state that the plugin works with "Eclipse 3.4.2 or 3.5". However, in my experience it works fine in Eclipse 3.6 too.